# Verificar se usuário esta realizando o login de dentro da empresa

Tags: angularjs, spring

Não vou entrar em detalhes da tecnologia usada, pois a dúvida é mais na melhor maneira de resolver esta situação. Tenho o seguinte cenário:

- Empresa com várias filiais;
- Essas filiais tem seus colaboradores;
- O sistema com o front-end em AngularJS e vários back-ends em Java já esta em produção há quase 1 ano.

Quando o colaborador realiza o login de qualquer lugar, ele tem acesso completo ao sistema, como já funciona normalmente. Porém, agora terá uma alteração, caso o usuário realizar o login em qualquer outro local, que não seja de dentro da empresa, ele terá acesso apenas a algumas partes do sistema.

Qual a melhor maneira de verificar se o usuário esta realizando login de dentro da empresa e assim liberando acesso completo ou de qualquer outro local e assim liberando apenas acesso parcial?

Comment: Ai está uma questão, pois você pode fazer isso usando `geolocation`, mas não sei se é a melhor forma para isso.

Comment: Na minha visão, isso deveria ser preocupação inicial da equipe de infra. Te oferecer um parâmetro pra você saber quando a requisição vêm da extranet.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma lista de ips confiáveis e qualquer ip fora desses só acessa partes do sistema. Uma coisa assim deveria ser controlada no back-end logo após a requisição de login. E aí no front você só exibe o que estiver de acordo com cada perfil.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Vinícius Mussato

No caso os ips mudam, pois são filiais no Brasil todo, seria complicado esse tipo de controle. Tenho pensado na ideia de dois (2) níveis de login:

 - O primeiro da filial (algum usuário master por exemplo);
 - O segundo do usuário, onde antes de conceder acesso ia verificar o estado do usuário máster;

Será que dessa forma da certo?

Comment: Funciona, ao invés de utilizar o ip vc vai utilizar o perfil do usuário. Acho que o ideal seria sempre que um usuário for criado ele ser por padrão o usuário com o menor nível de acesso. Daí teria um usuário adm que faz upgrades no perfil dele.

Comment: Dessa maneira o usuário master da filial efetuaria o login e manteria o estado. Os próximos usuários ao efetuar o login, faria uma verificação se o estado do usuário master esta online, assim teria acesso completo ou off-line, assim teria acesso parcial. @Vinícius Mussato funcionaria dessa maneira?